# Open Source HTTP Proxy Server for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

I'm looking for an Open Source HTTP Proxy Server for Windows Server 2008 supporting Active Directory based authentication.

Any ideas ?

Comment: oops.. meant to answer rather than comment

Answer (score 1):

[SquidNT](http://www.serassio.it/SquidNT.htm)(Squid port to Windows). You can use mswin_ntlm_auth.exe to user Authentication on a Windows domain.

Comment: Yes, but i'm looking for another alternative to SquidNT ...

Answer (score 0):

Apache on windows with mod_proxy and [mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) should fit the bill. Native builds for Windows (no cygwin nonsense) are distributed by ASF. Add in mod_disk_cache for performance imrpovements.

Note that users will still be prompted for a password (basic HTTP authentication), but it will authenticate against ACtive directory, so the same username and password will be used. If you want no sign-on prompts for the users (that is, using automatic NTLM authentication from IE rather than a basic authentication prompt), you will likely need [mod_ntlm2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modntlm/), build for Windows. I've never done that, but I assume it is possible, since all of the other baseline Apache modules build natively for Windows.